# VS2015 can't find Newtonsoft.Json converters?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, nuget, expandoobject

It feels like this should be so simple, but I'm very stuck on it. In VisualStudio 2015 with .Net4.5.2, I'm trying to deserialize JSON into a dynamic object in C#. I've added a NuGet package for Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0 and I've added the proper using statements:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
```

Then I create a dynamic object to hold the deserialized data:

```
dynamic _dynamic = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)) ? new ExpandoObject() : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(val, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

But at compile time, it complains about the ExpandoObjectConverter:

```
CS0246  C# The type or namespace name 'ExpandoObjectConverter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

In another solution, I can browse to ExpandoObjectConverter in Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll but in my new project, it "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret.".

Thoughts? I'm sure it will turn out to be something stupid I've missed. Thanks.

Comment: your referenced ddl might not be same as your project's framework.

Comment: You're suggesting that Newtonsoft.Json v9 uses an old version of .net?

Comment: yes, try using v4.0 or v4.5.

Comment: Okay now I've tried .NET 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, and 4.0. The same error occurs under each of those frameworks.

Comment: maybe you can still try them on the other .NET framework versions by reinstalling the package `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json` just to make sure if it gives any pointers :)

Comment: add this line in your `app.config`... `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />`